# Mathematics and logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For this indirect utility function:

v(y) = ln(1/3 y) + 2 ln (2/3 y)
     = 3 ln(y) + ln (4/27)

How did they simplify to 3 ln(y) + ln (4/27)?

Im a bit confused, if there is a site helping with this review it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ln\left(\frac 13 y\right) = \ln\frac 13 + \ln y$$
$$2 \ln\left(\frac 23 y\right) = 2 \ln\frac 23 + 2 \ln y$$
$$\ln\frac 13 + 2 \ln\frac 23 = \ln\frac 13 + \ln\left(\left(\frac 23\right)^2\right)
= \ln\left(\frac 13 \cdot \left(\frac 23\right)^2\right)$$

Put these facts together with 
$v(y) = \ln\left(\frac 13 y\right) + 2 \ln\left(\frac 23 y\right).$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:$$a\ln(m)=\ln(m^a)$$$$\ln(m)+\ln(n)=\ln(mn)$$